# Opening a computed document using window.open() and data: scheme

Tags: javascript, window.open, data-uri

I have a webpage running in a browser that generates a computed HTML document, and I want to open that document in a new browser tab.

The simple and dirty method is to do this:

```js
const w = window.open('', '_blank');
w.document.open();
w.document.write(htmlContents);
w.document.close();
```

Easy enough. But this has some awkward consequences that I do not like. Namely, the URL of the new tab has to point *somewhere*, but there is nowhere *to* point it at since the new document is computed on the fly. If I specify no URL, it uses the URL of my webpage. So if someone refreshed the tab containing the generated document, the document disappears and a new instance of my webpage loads in its place. This would be confounding to the user.

What I believe better suits my needs is to use a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) instead. I would simply encode the entire contents of my webpage into the URI itself, and use `window.open()` to open that URI. It's ugly, but semantically aligned with my goal: a standalone computed document that can't accidentally be navigated out of due to page refreshing.

I constructed what I thought was a trivially simple concept for this, like so:

```js
const doc = encodeURIComponent('<html><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>');
window.open(`data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${doc}`, '_blank');
```

If I run this code, a new window flashes on my screen for one frame before immediately closing. No error raised.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: "If I specify no URL, it uses the URL of my webpage" - I don't believe that's true. With an empty, it should just display "about:blank".

Comment: @Unmitigated It may be browser-dependent, but in my browser of choice (Firefox) running `window.open('', '_blank')` in the console duplicates the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [all modern browsers have explicitly blocked this use of Data URIs on purpose](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/). Wonderful.

Another tick on the chalkboard for "the singular very perfect thing I needed was taken away from us relatively recently". Ugh.

On the bright side, this seems to do everything I want even better:

```js
const html = '<html><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>';
const blob = new Blob([html], { type: 'text/html'});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```